# How can I install my windows service on a server so that it runs in the background on startup?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, timer, windows-services, windows-installer

I have a windows service that I coded last week, it's intention is to run a timer that checks periodically if the date has changed, if so it kicks off a method to get objects from our SQL server and if they match the current date it sends them off to another service that processes the payment. I am new to services, and am unsure of how to install this to get it to a) run in the background endlessly and b) run on startup in case of the server getting reset.

Here is the code for my Windows Service in VB.NET

```
Imports System.ServiceProcess
```

Imports AFI.BusinessObjects.Billing
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class FutureTransactionProcessor

```
'Creates a timer that can't be grabbed up by garbage collection
Private Timer As System.Timers.Timer

'Create a variable for todays date minus one to check against and see if the date has advanced.
Private lastRun As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)

Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    ' Add code here to start your service. This method should set things
    ' in motion so your service can do its work.

    'Timer that finishes its run every 10 minutes
    Timer = New System.Timers.Timer(10 * 60 * 1000)

    'we trigger a method as soon as the timer has finished running its course
    'Timer.Elapsed += New System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(AddressOf timerElapsed)
    AddHandler Timer.Elapsed, AddressOf timerElapsed

    'start our timer
    Timer.Start()

End Sub

Protected Sub timerElapsed(ByVal sender As Object, e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)

    If lastRun.Date < DateTime.Now.Date Then

        'stop the timer to perform our check against the FUTURE_TRANSACTIONS table
        Timer.Stop()

        'BEGIN FUNCTION TO RETURN FUTURE TRANSACTIONS FROM FUTURE_TRANSACTION TABLE THAT MATCH TODAYS DATE IF ANY
        GetFutureTransactionsByDate(DateTime.Now.Date)


        'reset our lastRun variable so we'll know when this method was last ran
        lastRun = DateTime.Now

        'restart our timer
        Timer.Start()

    End If


End Sub

Public Shared Function GetFutureTransactionsByDate(ByVal dateToday As DateTime) As FuturePaymentsCollection

    Dim FuturePaymentsToBeProcessed As FuturePaymentsCollection = New FuturePaymentsCollection

    Using cnSQL As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(AFI.Configuration.SystemSetting.Collection("ClientServer", "CS_Connection_String").SettingValue)

        Using cmdSP As New SqlCommand("PROC_FUTURE_TRANSACTIONS_SEL_BY_TODAY", cnSQL)

            cmdSP.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmdSP.Parameters.AddWithValue("DATETODAY", dateToday)

            cmdSP.Connection.Open()
            Dim sqlReader As SqlDataReader = cmdSP.ExecuteReader()

            If sqlReader.HasRows Then
                While (sqlReader.Read())
                    Dim futurePayment As FuturePayment = New FuturePayment

                    futurePayment.FutureTransactionID = sqlReader.GetInt32(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("BMW_TRANSACTION_ID"))
                    futurePayment.GroupID = sqlReader.GetInt32(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("BMW_CNTC_GROUP_ID"))
                    futurePayment.PayorAccountID = sqlReader.GetInt32(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("BMW_PAYOR_ACCOUNT_ID"))
                    futurePayment.PolicyID = sqlReader.GetInt32(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("BMW_POLICY_ID"))
                    futurePayment.AccountTypeID = sqlReader.GetInt32(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("BMW_ACCOUNT_TYPE_ID"))
                    futurePayment.TransationTypeID = sqlReader.GetInt32(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("BMW_TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID"))
                    futurePayment.TransactionDate = sqlReader.GetDateTime(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("BMW_TRANSACTION_DATE")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
                    futurePayment.TransactionSubmitter = sqlReader.GetInt32(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("BMW_TRANSACTION_SUBMITTER"))
                    futurePayment.TransactionAmount = sqlReader.GetDecimal(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("BMW_TRANSACTION_AMOUNT"))
                    futurePayment.TransactionLast4 = sqlReader.GetString(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("BMW_TRANSACTION_LAST4"))
                    futurePayment.TransactionEmail = sqlReader.GetString(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("BMW_TRANSACTION_EMAIL"))
                    futurePayment.PaymentInfo1 = sqlReader.GetString(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("PaymentInfo1"))
                    futurePayment.PaymentInfo2 = sqlReader.GetString(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("PaymentInfo2"))
                    futurePayment.PaymentInfo3 = sqlReader.GetString(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("PaymentInfo3"))
                    futurePayment.PaymentInfo4 = sqlReader.GetString(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("PaymentInfo4"))
                    futurePayment.PaymentInfo5 = sqlReader.GetString(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("PaymentInfo5"))
                    futurePayment.PaymentInfo6 = sqlReader.GetString(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("PaymentInfo6"))
                    futurePayment.TransactionUpdateDate = sqlReader.GetDateTime(sqlReader.GetOrdinal("BMW_TRANSACTION_UPDATE_DATE"))


                    FuturePaymentsToBeProcessed.Add(futurePayment)

                End While
            End If

            cmdSP.Connection.Close()

        End Using

    End Using


    'Return us a collection of FuturePayment Items
    Return FuturePaymentsToBeProcessed


    'For every item returned we need to turn it into a OneTimePayment object
    For Each Payment As FuturePayment In FuturePaymentsToBeProcessed

        Dim PaymentToBeProcessed As OneTimePayment

        PaymentToBeProcessed.PayorAccountId = Payment.PayorAccountID
        PaymentToBeProcessed.PolicyID = Payment.PolicyID
        PaymentToBeProcessed.AccountTypeID = Payment.AccountTypeID

        'Future payments can only be EFT so we'll go ahead and set that to 1
        PaymentToBeProcessed.PayTypeID = 1
        PaymentToBeProcessed.BankInfoName = Payment.PaymentInfo1
        PaymentToBeProcessed.BankInfoRoutingNum = Payment.PaymentInfo2
        PaymentToBeProcessed.BankInfoAccountNum = Payment.PaymentInfo3

        If PaymentToBeProcessed.BankInfoAccountNum.Length >= 4 Then
            PaymentToBeProcessed.Last4 = PaymentToBeProcessed.BankInfoAccountNum.Substring(PaymentToBeProcessed.BankInfoAccountNum.Length - 4, 4)
        Else
            PaymentToBeProcessed.Last4 = "XXXX"
        End If

        PaymentToBeProcessed.TransactionTypeID = 1
        PaymentToBeProcessed.Email = Payment.TransactionEmail
        PaymentToBeProcessed.TransactionAmount = Payment.TransactionAmount

        PaymentToBeProcessed.Save()
        PaymentToBeProcessed.SendPaymentToGateway()


        'Run our method to remove the future payment from the Future_Transactions table and enter it into the Future_Transactions_History table as processed
        Payment.ProcessFuturePayment(Payment.FutureTransactionID)



    Next

End Function



Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
    ' Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
End Sub
```

End Class

I have tried to right click the designer view on the service and add Installer and I've changed the serviceName and displayName properties on the ServiceInstaller1 and then I've changed the account property to LocalSystem for the ServiceProcessInstaller1. The next step my tutorial says is to build and then it should create a MyService.exe however when I search through my solutions files and folders I can't find this exe so I'm not sure why this isn't being created on build? Am I going about this the wrong way? Should I be kicking this off with Windows Task Scheduler or should I create an installer and install it on our server to run in the background consistently? Thanks for any information or help!

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to create an MSI.  The Service Installer classes are considered an antipattern because MSI already supports services. See:

[Building and Deploying a Windows Service using IsWiX](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJxU47_zqbw)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice, I'm following along in the video but I don't see a Windows Insaller XML I can add to my solution. Do I need to add IsWix to visual studio somehow? Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, I recommend separate solutions.  ISWIX doesn't support project references for this reason.  If you do same solution you'll need to add a project dependency to ensure correct build order.